# importerror: libgl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory (PyQt5)

Tags: docker, pyqt5, dockerfile

I am trying to run a simple PyQt5 application on a docker container. But when I am running my docker compose file I am getting the following error:

> from pyqt5.qtwidgets import * importerror: libgl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory.

**Can someone help me fix this problem?**

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Preparing work environment
ADD server.py .
ADD hinto.py .
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install python3
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
# Preparing work environment

RUN pip3 install PyQt5
```

as you can see I am installing the PyQt5 package so I do not understand where it got wrong.

Comment: libgl is not part of PyQt5. If PyQt5 were packaged correctly it would be a dependency, but clearly whoever did the Ubuntu packaging for this release missed it.

Comment: Wait, you're using `pip install`, not `apt install`. Never mind, not Ubuntu's fault; `pip` _can't_ install native executables; you need to use apt/dpkg/&c for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` isn't intended for installing native dependencies (like libgl, which is a C library, not a Python library). On Ubuntu, managing native dependencies is `apt-get`'s job.

Don't use `pip` to install software your distro has its own packages for. In this case, that looks like:

```
apt-get -y install python3-pyqt5
```

As you can see at https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/python3-pyqt5, this lists [`libqt5gui5`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libqt5gui5) as a dependency, which in turn depends on [`libgl1`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libgl1).